# Number of Associated Prime Ideals vs. Number of Maximal Ideals

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra

This is a very naive (and presumably basic) question, but suppose you have an ideal $I \subset R$ in a commutative Noetherian ring with unity.  Does the number of maximal ideals containing $I$ have any relation to the number of associated primes of $I$?  What if $R$ is Dedekind, or Artinian?

Thanks for any elucidation!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typically, $I$ is contained in infinitely many maximal ideals. For example, the ideal $(x) \subseteq k[x,y]$ is contained in all $(x,y-\alpha)$ for $\alpha \in k$. This corresponds to the geometric fact that there are infinitely many points on the $y$-axis.

If you replace *maximal* by *minimal containing $I$*, then there is always the obvious inequality: every prime ideal that is minimal over $I$ is an associated prime of $I$, but the converse need not hold.

Maybe you already know this, but an example of an associated prime that is not minimal is given by the prime ideal $(x,y)$ in $R = k[x,y]/(x^2,xy)$: it is the annihilator of $x$, but the only minimal prime of $R$ is $(x)$. Thus $(x,y)$ is an *embedded prime*.

(The name embedded prime comes from the fact that $V(x,y) \subsetneq V(x)$, i.e. the origin is an embedded component contained in the unique irreducible component.)

However, if $R$ is Dedekind, then either $I = 0$ which has no associated primes except $0$ itself, or $I \neq 0$, in which case every prime ideal containing $I$ is minimal over $I$ (since $R/I$ is Artinian). This is more a coincidence than a general philosophy.

Similarly, in an Artinian ring, there are no embedded primes, since there are no inclusions between the prime ideals.

Comment: Why don't mention that the number of minimal (associated) prime ideals is *finite* (to contrast with the number of maximal ones), at least whenever the ring is Noetherian?

Comment: Ah, fair point. I thought that the OP was aware of this fact, given the question about the number of associated prime ideals.